# How to solve Luke: error java.lang.RuntimeException: No valid directory at the location when trying to open lucene index directory?

Tags: lucene, luke

Im trying to read/analyze the index files but I get the error below when i try to open the lucene index directory

```
[2018-03-27 18:12:33,424] ERROR (LukeController.java:181) - Failed to open index: /Users/tucker/lux/2018/03/27/1522108807
java.lang.RuntimeException: No valid directory at the location: /Users/tucker/lux/2018/03/27/1522108807
```

Inside the directory `/Users/tucker/lux/2018/03/27/1522108807` i have files below

```
_1y.cfe         _84.cfe         _c2.cfe         _c4.cfe         _c6.cfe         _c8.cfe
_1y.cfs         _84.cfs         _c2.cfs         _c4.cfs         _c6.cfs         _c8.cfs
_1y.si          _84.si          _c2.si          _c4.si          _c6.si          _c8.si
_51.cfe         _c1.cfe         _c3.cfe         _c5.cfe         _c7.cfe         index.properties
_51.cfs         _c1.cfs         _c3.cfs         _c5.cfs         _c7.cfs         optimized_flag
_51.si          _c1.si          _c3.si          _c5.si          _c7.si          segments_10
```

Luke version 7.2.0 [github](https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke/releases)

Comment: it's strange that 7.2 Luke do not contain LukeController.java class, are you sure, that you're running correct version?

Comment: I used luke 6.0.0 and was able to see index

Comment: so, you are using 6.0.0 version and everything is working? or you want to use 7.2? What's your problem?

Comment: I used ver 6.0.0 and everything is working